# Porqué no me inserta la imagen en mi base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysqli

tengo un formulario con un codigo php que se dedica a enviar los datos nombre, precio e imagen a una base de datos y la inserte en una carpeta y en mi base me guarde la dirección.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```html
<?php
if(isset($enviar)){
 $name = clear($name);
 $price = clear($price);
 
 $imagen = "";
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])){
  $imagen = $name.rand(0,1000).".png";
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], "productos/".$imagen);
 }
 $mysql_query("INSERT INTO productosima (name,price,imagen) VALUES ('$name','$price','$imagen')");
 alert("Producto agregado");
 redir("?p=ejemploinsertardatos");
}

?>
 

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nombre del producto"/>
 </div>


 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Precio del producto"/>
 </div>


 <label>Imagen del producto</label>

 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagen" title="Imagen del producto" placeholder="Imagen del producto"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar"><i class= "fa fa-check"></i>  Agregar Producto</button>
    </div>
    

</form>
```

El formulario sale, me deja poner el archivo y todo, pero veo que luego cuando le doy al boton de enviar no se me guarda.

Comment: ¿Has mirado el log de Apache, a ver si indica algún error?

Comment: Log de Apache? que es?

Comment: como puedes saber si `isset($enviar)` si nunca fue declarado? el código está completo?

Comment: creo que en el button ultimo, cuando dice (((<div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar"><i class= "fa fa-check"></i>  Agregar Producto</button>
    </div>))))) especifico que cuando le de ahi se efectuara la funcion no?? ayuda

Comment: No, el botton lo que hace es un `submit`. Como el `action` del form está vacío, envia la información por método `POST` a si mismo (misma página) entonce `if(isset($enviar)){` deberías antes asignar `$enviar=$_POST['enviar'];`

Comment: como lo hago? creo una funcion o algo?

Comment: El log de Apache es el que guarda los errores de PHP, pues Apache es el encargado de interpretar el código Php.

Comment: Y como hago yo que me funcione el insertar imagen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si intentas añadir el nombre de la imagen a tu base de datos, podrías intentar poner en tu variable $imagen lo siguiente:

```
$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
```

O si intentas añadir la ruta en tu base de datos podrías intentar hacer esto:

```
$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$ruta = "C:/turuta/".$imagen;
$mysql_query("INSERT INTO productosima (name,price,imagen) VALUES 
('$name','$price',$imagen)");
```

Comment: Ojo en VALUES intenta no poner entre comillas la variable $imagen

Comment: Ok voy a probarlo, pero me falta algo en el codigo? esque el formulario se me presenta pero cuando le doy al boton no me introduce los datos.

Comment: te refieres al de el precio del producto, nombre del producto?

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, gracias a todos. la respuesta de Jorge ya me sirvio.